# How do I concatenate multiple form elements together and display them in a div as the user changes the values?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, textarea, concatenation

The textareas update but I'm not getting the values of the radio-buttons correctly.

HTML

```
<div class="row text-center" id="like">
<p>I like</p>
</div>

 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="fruit">
  <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="fruitName" id="option1" value="knowledge">apples</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="fruitName" id="option2" value="comprehension">oranges</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="fruitName" id="option3" value="application">banannas</label>
</div>

<div class="row text-center" id="because">
  <p>because</p>
</div>

<div class="row text-center">
  <textarea class="form-control" id="reason" rows="1" placeholder="why do you like them?">    </textarea>
</div>


<div><p id="output"></p></div>
```

JS

```
$('#fruit, #reason').bind('keypress blur', function() {
    var str = 'I like ' +  fruit.value  + ' because ' + reason.value + '.'
        output.innerHTML = str;    
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AL22k/

I think it would be better to use the **[map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** function, but I'm not sure how to set up the change handler.

Comment: `$('[name=fruitName]:checked').val()` e.g but you should start by reading some basic tutos

Comment: I have been. It's difficult to figure out exactly how to format the function though. I'm not sure where to find a good tutorial for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your looking for the value or text, but here it is with value.

```
var fruittxt = '____';
var reasontxt = '';

$('#reason').bind('keyup', function() {
        reasontxt = reason.value;
        update();
});

$('#fruit').change(function(){
    fruittxt = $('[name=fruitName]:checked').val();
    update();
});

function update(){
    var str = 'I like ' +  fruittxt  + ' because ' + reasontxt + '.';
    output.innerHTML = str;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AL22k/1/

Comment: +1 for providing more expected behaviour, looks more logical indeed

Comment: Amazing. This is so perfect and much easier to understand!